# Magento category is not getting update after upgrade 1.7 to 1.9?

Tags: php, magento

I have upgraded Magento 1.7 to 1.9. After upgrade category is not getting update. it is displayed only "Please wait" popup box only and it stay for a long time.
I thought it might re-index issue so i re-indexed it by index management.
and followed steps as mentioned below url:

[Magento save new category taking too much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486900/magento-save-new-category-taking-too-much-time)

but not any success. Kindly help out me if you know any other solutions for this.[image]

Comment: Need to update/Alter any table for this issue?

Comment: is the save request already fired? possibly you run in to this bug [Magento - JavaScript error prevents adding and saving of categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668533/magento-javascript-error-prevents-adding-and-saving-of-categories/34676041#34676041)

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be due to Magento 1.9 no longer having the thumbnail attribute for categories - a bad ommission if you ask me.  Your codebase looks like it is still rendering the field on the category edit screen, so you need to either remove it from your code, or (better option) re-add the thumbnail field to Magento - take a look at this very good description on how to do it https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48065/admin-category-insert-thumbnail-field-has-disappeared

Comment: Thanks for your great help and I tried but no success.  I have re-added the thumbnail field to Magento

Comment: sorry to hear that didnt cure it, have you checked the logs in var/log?

Answer (score 0):

When you save category magento fire a ajax just try to locate ajax error. Firstly just enable error reporting at index.php file.